# Large PHP Arrays Executing Improperly With MySQL Search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a grid of tiles representing a map.  When I select a certain tile, I create an array (not a matrix) of all tiles within a given distance of the selected tile.  Each tile is represented by a 5 character string which contains an x and y coordinate.  So an array at distance 1 from tile ['02-02'] would look like ['01-01','01-02', '01-03','02-01', etc...]

After I have that array, I do a search of a MySQL database to find rows which fall within the search array. So in the above example, if an object fell at 01-01 and another object fell at 03-03, the search would return the row for both objects.

All of this works perfectly for relatively small distances. I can search at a distance of 10 and even 100 without problem.  But as that distance increases, I start getting weird results.  My script runs multiple searches.  At distances between about 100 and 250, the first couple of MySQL queries run fine, but later queries don't return anything at all. Above 250 or so, I get a fatal error that I've run over the PHP maximum memory allocation.

Expanding the memory available to PHP is an easy fix, and I can handle that on my own.  I'm looking to figure out what's causing the error between 100 and 250.  When I started debugging, I tried printing out my search array to a browser to figure out what was inside.  As the script executes, the search array briefly prints... and then disappears from the browser when the next array prints. At the end of the script, even the final array which was printed disappears. I'm not aware of anything that would cause PHP to print HTML to a browser and then erase it after it's on the client side. It's totally bizarre.

[EDIT: After some time, the printed arrays appear.  I assume this is just a browser memory issue, but it doesn't address why the MySQL queries aren't printing the appropriate objects.]

I'm also not sure what would cause the search array to work fine for the first couple of searches and then start failing to return any objects later in the script.

I suppose that my question is two fold.  First, what would cause this bizarre (in my understanding) behavior and can it be fixed? Second, can someone suggest a better approach to implement the same functionality and avoid this problem in the first place?

Comment: How bout some code and / or SQL queries?

Comment: I think now that I've gotten my hands on the actual arrays that are getting printed, I may have found the problem.  It's not related to memory usage, which is what I was initially suspecting.  I'll delete this question if that turns out not to be the issue.